# Woocommerce Shop page variation product button replace with add to cart button

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am currently making an e-commerce on woocommerce. On my Shop/Catalog page, I used variation products which display select options button I need to remove this button to add to cart button.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you need to replace the button of select options with add to cart

Please check below code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_select_options_text' );
  function custom_select_options_text() {
  global $product;
  $product_type = $product->product_type;
  switch ( $product_type ) {
  case 'subscription':
  return __( 'Options', 'woocommerce' ); /*change 'Options' for Simple Subscriptions */
  case 'variable-subscription':
  return __( 'Options', 'woocommerce' ); /*change 'Options' for Variable Subscriptions */
  case 'variable':
  return __( 'Options', 'woocommerce' ); /*change 'Options' for Variable Products */
  case 'simple':
  return __( 'Add to Cart', 'woocommerce' ); /*change 'Add to Cart' for Simple Products */
  break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes that I want

Comment: Edited answer please check

Comment: Pratik Bhatt this been change only text, not functionality I want Select options button to replace with add to cart functionality.

Comment: I think it will not be possible as you need to select the options before adding the product to cart